# Twilio - why i get in call status is in-progress also completed and my phone not ringing yet

Tags: php, callback, twilio, twilio-php

this is my code :

```
require_once 'library/Twilio/autoload.php'
use Twilio\Rest\Client
account_sid ='ACXXXXXXX'
auth_token ='xxxxx'
twilio_number ='+1xxxx'
to_number = "+212xxxx"
client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token)
client->account->calls->create(  
    to_number,
    twilio_number,
    array("method" => "GET","statusCallback" => "https://xxx.php",
        "statusCallbackEvent" => array('initiated', 'ringing', 
        'answered','completed'),
        "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
        "url" => "http://xxx.php" 
    )
)
```

And this is the results of callstatus:
1-initiated
2-in-progress
3-completed

Comment: Is there anything in your [call logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/) that tells you more about the calls? Or perhaps in the [Twilio debugger](http://twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger)?

Comment: Array
(
    [Called] => +212xx
    [ToState] => 
    [CallerCountry] => US
    [Direction] => outbound-api
    [Timestamp] => Tue..
    [CallerState] => TX
    [ToZip] => 
    [SequenceNumber] => 1
    [CallSid] => CAxx
    [To] => +212xx
    [CallerZip] => 
    [ToCountry] => MA
    [ApiVersion] => 2010-04-01
    [CalledZip] => 
    [CalledCity] => 
    [CallStatus] => in-progress
    [From] => +1xx
    [AccountSid] => ACxx
    [CalledCountry] => MA
    [CallerCity] => 
    [Caller] => +1xx
    [FromCountry] => US
    [FromZip] => 
    [FromState] => TX
)

Comment: That is not phenomenally helpful ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Did you check the call logs and debugger like I suggested?

Comment: that's what i found in Twilio debugger :21626 - Invalid 'StatusCallbackEvent'=>Invalid events for callSid: CAXXX invalid statusCallbackEvents queued

Comment: Looks like you were asking for an event that doesn't exist? Can you check your event list and try making the call again and see what happens to the call and in your debugger?

Comment: Event list ? you mean this : statusCallbackEvent" => array('queued','initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'),

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your final comment you show that you are using `array('queued','initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed')` as your `statusCallbackEvent` parameter. When making calls with the REST API [the only available events that you can subscribe to are `initiated`, `ringing`, `answered` and `completed`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#statuscallbackevent).

You may find that the `CallStatus` parameter you receive is one of `queued`, `initiated`, `ringing`, `in-progress`, `busy`, `failed`, or `no-answer` but those are the available statuses, not the available events to subscribe to.

Ensure that you are only requesting the events `initiated`, `ringing`, `answered` and `completed` and your call should be fine.

Comment: that what i did in  my last code at statusCallbackEvent :"statusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated","ringing","answered","completed") . and this is the list of call status what i got :initiated, ringing, in-progress, completed.

Comment: Like you see there is no call status have answered/no-answer and that what i want ,because i wanna to make conditions if the the call is answered or not

Comment: Right, so the status `in-progress` means that the call has been answered. The statuses `busy`, `failed` and `no-answer` means the call was not answered.

Comment: Cool! If this answers your question, please mark it as correct so that others who come across this can see it helped too. Thanks!