# how i can get numbers related with my account sid - PHP

Tags: php, twilio

i was wondering if possible to get numbers related with my account with using php

```
require_once 'library/Twilio/autoload.php'
use Twilio\Rest\Client

account_sid ='AC5xxx'
auth_token ='896xxx'
```

what else ?
any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Check out the docs for [Reading multiple IncomingPhoneNumber resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers#read-multiple-incomingphonenumber-resources).

It includes this sample code:

```
// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$incomingPhoneNumbers = $twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers
                           ->read();

foreach ($incomingPhoneNumbers as $record) {
    print($record->sid);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: that's really helpful thank you , i have another probleme https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299011/twilio-why-i-get-in-call-status-is-in-progress-also-completed-and-my-phone-not check it please